# how to store a jsp file in sql table and to execute it?

Tags: java, sql, jsp

1. First I took a query and tokenized it using stringtokenizer method and stored those tokens in a list.
2. I matched these tokens with a table contents.
3. If there is a match I need to execute the corresponding jsp file of the matched token.

How can we do this in java?

```
while (st.hasMoreElements()) 
{
    list.add(st.nextElement().toString());
}

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
{
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from rultree");
    while (rs.next()) 
    {
        if (rs.getString("name").equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(i)))
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
    }
}
```

I retrieved the matched tokens... now I want to retrieve the jsp file of matched token and execute it

Comment: The most common purpose of jsp file is to render information as HTML. Storing jsp file in a SQL table doesn't sound right to me and might indicate you're doing something wrong in your application design. Perhaps you should explain more what you're trying to do, and also explain to us what is your understanding of java, jsp, etc?

Answer (score 3):

JSPs are one of the template engines that you can't easily store in the database. Not that it's right to do it with other template engines, but at least it's possible.

JSPs are compiled to servlets, so they need to be present on the filesystem (unless you run the jsp-to-servlet compiler of the servlet container manually, but that's non-standard). If you want to dynamically load a jsp (still from the filesystem), then simply use:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/" + jspName + ".jsp").forward(request, response)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just take the jsp file from the root classpath of the war file instead? I was just trying that today and I couln't get out of the scope of the war classpath in any way, even by providing the file:/// prefix